# CV_CAP_OPENNI doesn't work with me

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, kinect, openni

I'm using kinect with OpenCV. I configured it without Cmake. I have included everything but when I write the following code :

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <cv.h>
 #include <highgui.h>
 #include <XnCppWrapper.h>


 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

   int main()
     {
Mat image = imread("c:\\im.jpg");
imshow("image",image);
VideoCapture Cap (CV_CAP_OPENNI);
if (!Cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "wrong";
}

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

I get the word "wrong" on the screen. I think there is a problem with Xncore.dll How can I add it or what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile opencv from souce with openni support. The pre compiled binaries don't have it by default.

Comment: Hi, Where can I get the source from? from this link (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) it just links to sourceforge where the tarballs are (which is what I used)